# What to do if KNN has K+ matches

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

We run a 3-NN classifier. 
We are looking at a case in which a point has 5 points (or something greater than K, which is 3 at the moment) of equal distance.

What can we do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" answer to this question. Two options are: (1) have a tie-breaking rule; or (2) just use all of them (in your example, all 5). There might be other options. I'd suggest that you try different options and see what works best for your particular application.

Comment: thank you.  that tie-breaking rule is something I dont know about.